# U2 Universe Update Multi value field errror

Tags: multivalue, universe

I am using the Universe U2.net toolkit to update the record in universe database. We have so far no issue with update to non multi value field with the following code

```
Open_Again:
    Try
        db_connectionU2 = openConnU2()
        db_connectionU2.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        GoTo Open_Again
    End Try

    Dim cmdWIP As New U2Command
    'cmdWIP = New U2Command("DELETE FROM MPS", db_connectionU2)
    cmdWIP = New U2Command("UPDATE POH SET EPOS=@FLAG where PONO='C11447'", db_connectionU2)
    cmdWIP = New U2Command("UPDATE CURCVRD F8=@F8 where F0='51747*1'", db_connectionU2)
    cmdWIP.Parameters.Add(New U2Parameter("@F8", U2Type.VarChar)).Value = "t"
    cmdWIP.Connection = db_connectionU2
    cmdWIP.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmdWIP.Dispose()
    cmdWIP = Nothing

    db_connectionU2.Close()
    db_connectionU2.Dispose()
    db_connectionU2 = Nothing
```

but it having the problem when we try to add in to multivalue field. It's return the error " Column being update from single to multi is illegal. Please see the red box for the message and the value we are writing in.

Please click below to see the screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfhWj.png)

Thank you

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641646/u2-universe-update-a-multivalue-field). In particular my post about Dynamic Normalization.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the DICT of that file and make sure your entries are marked and MultiValued and have an Multi-Value Association.

Here is an example from the HS.SALES demo account.

```
>LIST DICT CUSTOMER
DICT CUSTOMER    03:56:47pm  01 Dec 2016  Page    1

               Type &
Field......... Field. Field........ Conversion.. Column......... Output Depth &
Name.......... Number Definition... Code........ Heading........ Format Assoc..

CUSTID         D    0               P(0N)        Customer ID     10R    S
@ID            D    0                            CUSTOMER        10L    S
SAL            D    1                            Salutation      5T     S
FNAME          D    2                            First Name      12T    S
LNAME          D    3                            Last Name       16T    S
COMPANY        D    4                            Company Name    20T    S
ADDR1          D    5                            Address line 1  30T    S
ADDR2          D    6                            Address line 2  30T    S
CITY           D    7                            City            12T    S
STATE          D    8               P(2A)        State           2L     S
                                    MCU
ZIP            D    9               P(5N)        Zip             5L     S
PHONE          D   10               P("("3N")"3N Telephone       13R    S
                                    -4N)
PRODID         D   11               P(1A4N)      Product         5L     M ORDER
                                                                        S
SER_NUM        D   12               P(6N)        Serial#         6L     M ORDER
                                                                             S
```

Notice how PRODID has "M ORDERS" after is (the is drops to the next line thanks to the 80 char size of my terminal. This tells Universe that it is a multivalued field with an Association called ORDERS. This allows the SQL interpreter to know how to update things.

It gets a bit more complicated and I would recommend looking up HS.ADMIN and specifically HS.SCRIB for tips on formatting things for non-pick style consumption. Check the UVodbc guide for more info on that.